# Complex Analysis: Integration in Multiply Connected Domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to integrate $f(z)=\dfrac{cosh(4z)}{(z-4)^3}$ with respect to $z$ over $C$, where $C$ consists of $|z|=6$ counterclockwise and $|z-3|=2$ clockwise.

$z=4$ is not in $C$ (it is inside $|z-3|=2$). So, $f(z)$ is analytic in $C$.

From what I understand, my book says that since $f(z)$ is analytic, we could write $\int_{|z|=6}f(z)=\int_{|z-3|=2}f(z)$ if they would both be integrated the same direction. But since we have one clockwise and one counterclockwise, i guess we have $\int_{|z|=6}f(z)=-\int_{|z-3|=2}f(z)$.

So, $\int_{|z|=6}f(z) +\int_{|z-3|=2}f(z) = 0$

If I can write $\int_{C}f(z) = \int_{|z|=6}f(z) +\int_{|z-3|=2}f(z)$, my integral would be zero (which is the right answer according to the book), but I'm not sure if and why I would be able to do that?

Comment: These are oriented integrals.  It's not clear to me exactly what you are unsure about, but you seem to be using $\int_{|z-3|=2}$ both for the integral in the positive (counterclockwise) direction, and for the integral in the negative direction.  This is incorrect, and perhaps the source of your confusion.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to rewrite $\int_{C}$ as two integrals (one with $|z|=6$ and one with $|z-3|=2$), I think that might be my problem. In the post i wrote that $\int_{C} = \int_{|z|=6} + \int_{|z-3|=2}$, but I don't know if that is correct. Wouldn't it be $\int_{C} = \int_{|z|=6} - \int_{|z-3|=2}$, since the second integral goes in the other direction?

Comment: Yes, the second way is correct, and the first isn't.  That's what I was getting at.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But then I don't get how the correct answer could be zero.

I guess I should use this forumla: $g^(n)(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}$

In my case, $n=2$, $a=4$, $g(z)=cosh(4z)$.
$g''(4)=cosh16$.

So, $cosh16 = \frac{2!}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{cosh(4z)}{(z-4)^3}$.

$\int_{C} \frac{cosh(4z)}{(z-4)^3} = \pi i cosh16 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Cauchy integral formula, the singularity is inside both disks, and the positively-oriented integrals give the same value.  It isn't even necessary to work out exactly what it is.  Then when we subtract the integrals, we get $0$.

Comment: Thank you! How do I know that the integrals give the same value? I guess it's some theorem or so, but do you know what it is called (i.e. what to google to read about this)?

Comment: Cauchy integral formula